# Wildcard for BigI

Tags: sql, database, oracle, biginteger

I am using an orcale database to create a filtering system in java and want to display the customer id, which type is `big integer` in my program. Usually I am using sth like that

```
SELECT DISTINCT project.NAME 
FROM project INNER JOIN cust ON project.CUST_ID = cust.CUST_ID 
WHERE project.NAME like  '%' 
AND  cust.CUST_ID like '%' ;
```

However I am getting, `column ambiguously defined`

That is because cust is BigInteger and like does not work here. Basically, I want to have in the where part the `AND cust` structure, because of my filtering. However, I want to display all BigInteger ids. What could I use so that I can get all values for `cust`?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: In plain English, what customers do you want?

Comment: @DanBracuk I want a wildcard which gives me all customers back, just like with `project.Name like '%' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `column ambiguously defined` is anything to do with types; it's to do with column *names*. It typically happens when you include a column in your select clause that appears on more than one of the tables that are joined in your query. Try giving your tables aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.NAME 
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN cust c ON (c.CUST_ID = p.CUST_ID)
WHERE p.NAME LIKE '%' 
AND  c.CUST_ID LIKE '%';
```